# Email validation in registration form to exclude example addresses

Tags: magento-1, email, form-validation

My current registration form only validates the proper input email format.
 Where my `validation.js` file has

```
['validate-email', 'Please enter a valid email address. For example johndoe@domain.com.', function (v) {
            //return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /\w{1,}[@][\w\-]{1,}([.]([\w\-]{1,})){1,3}$/.test(v)
            //return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^[\!\#$%\*/?|\^\{\}`~&\'\+\-=_a-z0-9][\!\#$%\*/?|\^\{\}`~&\'\+\-=_a-z0-9\.]{1,30}[\!\#$%\*/?|\^\{\}`~&\'\+\-=_a-z0-9]@([a-z0-9_-]{1,30}\.){1,5}[a-z]{2,4}$/i.test(v)
            return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*@([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*\.(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]){2,})$/i.test(v)
        }],
```

What I want is my email to limit example email addresses such as test@test.com, email@domain.com, abc@abc.com etc also I want to limit the characters count to no more than 25 characters.

Comment: no answers yet ?